# What is the meaning of "a trip and a kick "?

Tags: meaning

> We felt that the sea had changed. There was **a trip and a kick** to
>   her dance.  This is from "The Manner of Men" by Kipling.

https://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/k/kipling/rudyard/limits/chapter19.html

The ship is now under a big storm and getting nearer to the land.(the sea had changed.)

I do not understand the meaning  of "a trip and a kick "

I am glad if some one would kindly teach me.

Comment: It means that the sea had become more dangerous, could trip or kick the unwary. The "dance" is an analogy. Imagine an unfriendly dance partner who won't do you any favours.

Answer (score 1):

The narrator uses the metaphor of dancing to describe the interaction of the ship and the sea. If the ship is dancing with the sea, then the sea has become a treacherous dance partner, tripping and kicking the ship figuratively, putting the ship in danger and distress.